# Remove everything except the text in parenthesis

Tags: php

I have a script below but it is outputting the following Testing) instead of the desired Testing. Ideally, I am trying to keep everything between the parenthesis and get rid of everything else.

```
$value= Test (Testing)
echo substr($value, strpos($value, "(") +1, strpos($value, ")") - strpos($value, "("));
```

What is the best way to create a new string only with the text in between the parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo preg_replace("/.*\((.*?)\).*/","$1",$value);
```

Comment: Assuming it's always the content of the last paranthesis only he wants, this is a good, concise solution.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract one from the length parameter to [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr):

```
$value = 'Test (Testing) Text';
$left = strpos( $value, "(");
echo substr( $value, $left + 1, strpos( $value, ")") - $left - 1);
```

This [outputs](http://3v4l.org/r6qhq):

```
Testing
```